# converting extracted html content in to pdf and giving option to download using php

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I have an html content stored in a variable.I have to generate a pdf file before giving it for download

like for example $content="test document containing test content"

Im trying to add this to a pdf file and give user the option to download it.

Ive tried the code

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/pdf; charset=utf-8');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.pdf');

$output = fopen('output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, $content);
?>
```

This gives the option to download file as pdf, bt when I try opening it in pdf reader, it shows file type nt supported.. Is ther anyother way to do this in php??

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a variable with your values, here $content, it's really quick to make it a PDF using **FPDF** (http://www.fpdf.org).

For example with your variables:

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$content);
$pdf->Output();
```

Moreover, if you want your user to download directly the file, write:

```
$pdf->Output("Name.pdf","D");
```

Note that no information has to be sent before Output(); !

Comment: seems like it wrked...I It doesnt show any error, bt it wnt download either.. checked in firebug..the response seems to have issue with font..

Comment: then you can try with $file=base64_encode($pdf->Output($filename,"S")); and later use base64_decode to read it in a new window or popup in javascript for example.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand what you're saying correctly, then you are just trying to output some html as a PDF file. That is not how it works. You need to generate a PDF, and then put this content in there.

I'd suggest taking a look at [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html).

For downloading take a look [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Pdf-how-to-output-for-download-td663453.html)

Comment: Ive tried dompdf..bt gives me an error deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime()

Comment: will this give me the option to download the file too or is it just realtime pdf generator?